# How do I get previous value from SharedFlow after Activity recreate/Configuration change in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-sharedflow

Suppose I have `ScanActivity` using jetpack compose that can scan Barcode, the result will shown in `TextField` and result will survive from configuration change(e.g screen rotation). I won't use `StateFlow` because after the result shown then I rotate my screen it will call API again, but the result become empty I want to keep the result.

ScanActivity:

```
class ScanActivity : BaseActivity(){

    private val scanViewModel: ScanViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   
    setContent {
      val detectedBarcode by scanViewModel.detectedBarcode.collectAsState(initial = null)
    
     LaunchedEffect(detectedBarcode){                
    //API Call
    ...
    //
      scanViewModel.setBarcodeField(detectedBarcode?.rawValue ?: "")
    }
    
    MyTextField()

}}
```

ScanViewModel:

```
class ScanViewModel: ViewModel(){

    val detectedBarcode = MutableSharedFlow<Barcode>()
    val barcodeResultField = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setBarcodeField(barcode: String) {
        barcodeResultField.postValue(barcode)
    }
}
```

My TextField:

```
@Composable
fun MyTextField(scanViewModel: ScanViewModel = viewModel()){
    val barcode by scanViewModel.barcodeResultField.observeAsState("")
    TextField(value = barcode, onValueChange = {brc ->
            scanViewModel.setBarcodeField(brc)
        },
            label = {
                Text(text = "Barcode Field")
            })

}
```

Comment: `sharedFlow` is designed for one time event just like `Channel`

Comment: @RaBaKa78 That’s not true. You can pass a replay amount to its constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I forget about that, Thank you for the remainder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your SharedFlow a replay amount of 1 so it replays the most recent emission to new subscribers.

```
val detectedBarcode = MutableSharedFlow<Barcode>(replay = 1)
```